# How to send signal to child process in Java?

Tags: java, process

java.lang.Process has a method called destroy(). The document said:

> The subprocess represented by this Process object is forcibly terminated.

I wanna know which signal is send when destroy() is called ?

I am using Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming by 'which signal is send when destroy is called?' you are referring to the actual system call. (I can't comment on your main question yet to ask you to confirm)

After quickly digging through the OpenJDK implementation source for ProcessBuilder I was able to find that the actual call ends up being a native cal.. (well no duh! :p)

After reviewing the native source from the appropriate methods:

- Windows: TerminateProcess((HANDLE) handle, 1);
- UNIX: kill(pid, SIGTERM);

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

From googling it suggests SIGTERM is used. I couldn't find a reference for this but it seems reasonable.

Comment: I think an experiment will make this question clear.  Thanks.